# Sort a string array in Alphabetical Order - C++ 11

Tags: arrays, string, c++11

I'm preparing for an interview and while looking across candidate experiences i came across the following question -

Given an array of strings : { “Sdjksajd”, “Skjdasjj”, “Bjsdakja”, “Xhudhau”, “Eeeeggg”, “Chrome”}. Display them in alphabetical order without using library functions .

I'm not very good at coding so i tried doing this using my limited knowledge in the following way:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
string selsort(string s);

string selsort(string s)
{
int i=0,j,k=0;
string min=&s[i];
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<6;j++)
    {
        if(s[j][k]<s[i][k])
        {
            string *temp;
            min=s[j];
            *temp=s[i];
            s[i]=s[j];
            s[j]=*temp;
        }
        else if(s[j][k]=s[i][k])
        {
                while(k<=s[j].length())
                {
                k++;
                selsort(string s);
                }
             }

        }
   }
     return s;
}

 int main()
 {
     int i;
     string s[6]={"Sdjksajd","Skjdasjj","Bjsdakja","Xhudhau","Eeeeggg","Chrome"};

  s=selsort(s);
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  cout<<s[i];
  return 0;
  }
```

However, i am getting "Error: invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript" and i think my program needs many more modifications to make it work. How exactly can i solve this question?

Comment: The correct answer is "it is not possible to display anything without using library functions".

Comment: While that's true, i think they meant for us to solve it without using library functions to sort or compare the string elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the problem specifies that you can't just *use* a library sort, it doesn't mean that you can't be *inspired* by a library sort.

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

Also note the extra restrictions on `RandomIt`: it must be ValueSwappable (and dereference to a movable type). Note that a pointer into an array is a `RandomIt`, and strings are `Swappable`

So we have two parts:

- Compare things
- Re-arrange things

For the moment, let's assume that we have a `Compare` (we will define one later)

Now an obvious property of a sorted collection is that the first element is less than every other element. We can imagine a function `RandomIt min_element(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp)` that finds the smallest element of a range. Thus we can swap the first element with the smallest, then carry on with the rest of the range. Thus sort becomes:

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp )
{
    for (RandomIt it = first; it != last; ++it)
    {
        RandomIt min = min_element(it, last, comp);
        swap(*it, *min);
    }
}
```

Now we need to implement `min_element`. We can just go through the range, using `Compare` to hold onto the current min.

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
RandomIt min_element( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp )
{
    RandomIt min = first;
    for (RandomIt it = first; it != last; ++it)
    {
        if (comp(*it, *min)) { min = it; }
    }
    return min;
}
```

And also we need `swap`

```
template< typename T >
void swap(T & lhs, T & rhs)
{
    T temp = static_cast<T&&>(lhs);
    lhs = static_cast<T&&>(rhs);
    rhs = static_cast<T&&>(temp);
}
```

Now we have our sorting function, we just need to be able to compare `std::string`s alphabetically. Luckily for us `<` is defined for strings to do this, so we just have:

```
bool string_less(const std::string & lhs, const std::string & rhs)
{
    return lhs < rhs;
}
```

We can put this all together into

```
void string_sort(std::string * values, std::size_t count)
{
    sort(values, values + count, string_less);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I solved it with a friend's help. It seems we were missing the string comparison function "bool string_less" which would help in comparing the strings.